# Symfony 3.3.16 Doctrine Relations & Dictonary tables for fast data processing with Foms based on EntityType, can't pass choiced value to database

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

it's not a typical approach where "user adds article". This approach is a try to build nicely configurable, and data validated (by forms on frontend) table in database contains data based from other tables - something I'm trying to call "Dictonary tables", and store ID  in main table of of vchar representation in other tables

This approach gives me a table which is very fast to process data on it.

Unfortunately, I encountered some difficulties using EntityType in forms

Adding ORM relation to entity (ConfigTable.php) causes writing null into database (POST have all values properly seted)

**UPDATE 2018.02.15**
annotation

```
@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\yourentity", inversedBy="mappedByFieldName")
@ORM\JoinColumn(name="field_in_current_entity_declared_as_ORM@/Column")

protected $entityOne
```

**@ORM\JoinColum is nt working properly here. Setting "name" attribute pointing to existing field can't create proper foreign keys.**

If JoinColumn is not setted at all - FK are pointing to your current annotated field wits suffix _id

**ie entity_one_id**

and variables are saved from form,
but if in *JoinColumn* you set `*name="pointing_to_field_annotaded_as_column_for_doctrine"*`
during saving data to database you will get error of that object

```
*YourBundle/Entity/EntityName - cannot be converted to INT*
```

DefaultController.php

```
/**
     * @param Request $request
     * @Route("/add", name="action_configtable_add")
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function addFieldConfigTableAction(Request $request)
    {
            $form = $this->createForm(ConfigTableFormType::class);

            $form->handleRequest($request);


            if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
                    $data = $form->getData();

                    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                    $em->persist($data);
                    $em->flush();

                    return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
            }

            return $this->render(
                ':Forms/ConfigTable:add.config.table.item.html.twig',
                [
                    'cdata' => $form->createView(),
                ]
            );
    }
```

MainEntity - in which I would like to store ID from dictonary entities (DictonaryOne.php, OtherDictonary.php)

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Class ConfigTable
 * @package AppBundle\Entity
 *          @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ConfigTableRepository")
 *          @ORM\Table(name="config_table")
 */
class ConfigTable
{
        /**
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         */protected $id;
        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true )
         */protected $dictonaryOne;
        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true )
         */protected $dictonaryTwo;


        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\DictonaryOne", inversedBy="configTableOne", cascade={"persist"})
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="dictonary_one")
         */
         protected $dictOne;


        //usual getters & setters

}
```

DictonaryOne Entity (binded by relation, cant save it's id into database in ConfigTable)

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;


use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Class DictonaryOne
 * @package AppBundle\Entity
 *          @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\DictonaryOneRepository")
 *          @ORM\Table(name="dictonary_one")
 */
class DictonaryOne
{
        /**
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         */protected $id;
        /**
         * @var string
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
         */
        protected $name;
        /**
         * @var string
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
         */
        protected $description;
        /**
         * @var boolean
         * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", options={"default":1})
         */
        protected $isActive;
        /**
         * @var int
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer", options={"default":"1"})
         */
        protected $orderField;

        /**
         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\ConfigTable", mappedBy="dictOne")
         */
        protected $configTableOne;


        public function __construct()
        {
                $this->configTableOne = new ArrayCollection();
        }
                    //usual getters & setters and:

        /**
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function getConfigTableOne()
        {
                return $this->configTableOne;
        }

        /**
         * @param mixed $configTableOne
         */
        public function setConfigTableOne(ConfigTable $configTableOne)
        {
                $this->configTableOne = $configTableOne;
        }


}
```

OtherDictonary Entity: (not binded by relation, data are stored in database corectly after submit)

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Class OtherDictonary
 * @package AppBundle\Entity
 *          @ORM\Entity()
 *          @ORM\Table(name="other_dictonary")
 */

class OtherDictonary
{
        /**
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         */protected $id;
        /**
         * @var string
         * @ORM\Column(type="string")
         */
        protected $name;
        /**
         * @var string
         * @ORM\Column(type="string")
         */
        protected $description;
        /**
         * @var boolean
         * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
         */
        protected $isActive;
        /**
         * @var int
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         */
        protected $orderField;

            //usual getters & setters

        /**
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function getId()
        {
                return $this->id;
        }

        public function __toString()
        {
                return (string)$this->id;
        }
}
```

ConfigTableFormType.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use AppBundle\Entity\DictonaryOne;
use AppBundle\Entity\OtherDictonary;

use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ConfigTableFormType extends AbstractType
{
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
                $builder
                    ->add(
                        'dictonaryOne',
                        EntityType::class,
                        [
                            'class'=> DictonaryOne::class,
                            'label'        => 'label from dictonary 1',
                            'choice_value' => 'id',
                            'choice_label' => 'description',
                            'expanded'     => false,
                            'multiple'     => false,
                                // 'mapped' => false, //not working
                        ]
                    )
                    ->add(
                        'dictonaryTwo',
                        EntityType::class,
                        [
                            'class' => OtherDictonary::class,
                            'label'         => 'label from other dictonary ',
                            'choice_value'  => 'id',
                            'choice_label'  => 'description',
                            'query_builder' => function (\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository $er) {
                                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('d2')
                                        ->andWhere('d2.isActive = 1')
                                        ->orderBy('d2.description', 'ASC');
                            },
                        ]
                    );
        }

        public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
        {
                $resolver->setDefaults(
                    [
                        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\ConfigTable',
                    ]
                );
        }

        public function getBlockPrefix()
        {
                return 'app_bundle_config_table_form_type';
        }
}
```

Comment: I’m sorry, it’s really hard to understand what your problem is and what you’re trying to achieve. Can you please put some effort into clarifying your problem statement and the steps you’ve already tried to solve it?

Comment: I (and most certainly nobody else from this community) will install your project and run it. Please create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of throwing a bunch of code at us. Tell us what you want to achieve and let us know what you’ve already tried.

Comment: @lxg well? is it clear now? - can You help?

Comment: Sorry, I had a look yesterday, but I don’t know what the problem is. I’m not really an expert on Symfony forms, as I usually work with REST APIs and pure HTML/JS frontends.

Comment: 2018.02.15 question updated, discovering some new interesting things

Answer (score 0):

in ORM annotation, reference JoinColumn(name="xxx") is pointless.

try don't use notation:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\DictonaryOne", inversedBy="configTableOne", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="dictonary_one")
     */
     protected $dictOne;
```

use:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\DictonaryOne", inversedBy="configTableOne", cascade={"persist"})
     */
     protected $dictOne;
```

**foreign keys are formed well by symfony.** Checked versions:

```
 Symfony 2.8 - 3.3.16, 
"doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6", (1.8.1)
"doctrine/orm": "^2.5", (v2.5.14)
```